# PHP: path is incorrect while running script from cron

Tags: php, linux, cron, include, filesystems

I'm having a strange problem. When I call script with http request (from browser) it works as it should. But when I'm calling it with cron include starts complaining on paths. Why can paths be ok while running the script in a common way an incorrect in cron? I've tried to use absolute paths, but it did not help.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Please provide more information. In its current state, this question will be voted closed as off-topic. A code example showing both the relative and absolute forms would be great please.

Comment: File permissions/ownership as to what user the script is ran under

Comment: show some code! However, do you do a require/include in the file? Could be your relative path is f*cked up. Use `__DIR__` instead

Comment: if you use a relative path in PHP files mostly in `require()` or `include()` then when called from browser it will be in the correct context, but once called from shell, it will consider current path as base path and try to find relative includes there, so you may want to add `cd path.for.base.folder` before calling `php file.to.run.php`

Comment: well, there's only `include_once "DB/mysql.php"`

Comment: @Yazan, but I'm having absolute paths in path var at php.ini

Comment: yes `include_once "DB/mysql.php";` mostly such lines causes your problem, i am not sure about vars in php.ini, though in your `include_once()` you are using nothing as prefix,i mean as init-path or so  so i am not sure if that php.ini thin is applied here, give it a try and `cd` to base folder before calling `php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I solved this with a code like this:

```
include_once __DIR__ . '/DB/mysql.php';
```